# Punto de silla en C

Tags: array, c, matriz

Tengo que encontrar el punto de silla en una matriz. La matriz se genera cargando una secuencia de números de un fichero. En este caso la matriz es 4x3. Por alguna razón mi código siempre que se ejecuta dice que el punto de silla está en la posición 0, fila 3 y columna 0, esto no es cierto. El fichero tiene la siguiente secuencia de números: 3 -4 8 5 2 7 12 7 9 0 1 2. Mi error esta en algún lugar entre los bucles for. Las coordenadas no son las correctas. Mi resultado esperado es "El punto de silla es 7 y esta en la fila 2 y en la columna 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define M 4
#define N 3
void escribeMat(int matriz[M][N]);
int Punto_de_silla_Mat(int matriz[M][N]);
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int matriz[M][N];
    FILE *fichero;
    fichero = fopen("C:\\Users\\***\\Documents\\****\\Ficheros\\numeros2.txt", "r");
    if (fichero == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error, el archivo no se ha abierto correctamente");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0; i<M; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<N; j++)
            {
                fscanf(fichero, "%d", &matriz[i][j]);

            }
        }
        escribeMat(matriz);
        Punto_de_silla_Mat(matriz);
        return 0;
    }
}
void escribeMat(int matriz[M][N])  //function that prints the matrix on screen
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<M; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            printf("%3d", matriz[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int Punto_de_silla_Mat(int matriz[M][N])
{
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    int P_fila=0,P_columna=0, encontrado=0;
    for(i=0; i<M; i++)
    {
        P_fila=i; //row
        P_columna=j; //column
        encontrado=0; //flag
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            if(matriz[i][j] < matriz[P_fila][P_columna])
            {
                P_fila = i;
                P_columna = j;
            }
        }
        for(k=0; k<M; k++)
        {
            if(matriz[k][P_columna] > matriz[P_fila][P_columna])
            {
                encontrado = 1;
                break;
                //return encontrado;
            }
            /*else 
                encontrado = 0;
                break;
                //return encontrado;*/
        }
        if(encontrado==0)
        {
            break;
            j=0;
        }

    }
    if(encontrado == 1)
    {
        printf("El punto de silla es %d y esta en la fila %d y en la columna %d", matriz[P_fila][P_columna], P_fila, P_columna); //saddle point number + position
    }
    else
        printf("No hay punto de silla"); //there is no saddle point.
    return 0;
            
}
```

Ejemplo de ejecución:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Había pensando en hacer que la función que calcula el punto de silla devuelva 1 o 0 dependiendo si ha encontrado un punto de silla y luego hacer un if en la función main. No se si es posible, el problema es que no podría especificar las coordenadas del punto de silla, verdad?

Comment: Tu función es demasiado grande y difícil de entender. Recomiendo dividirlo en funciones más pequeñas. Quizás pequeñas funciones como `int Minimo_en_fila(int matriz[M][N], int fila)` y `int Maximo_en_columna(int matriz[M][N], int columna)` ayudaría. Ellos deberían devolver índices y no elementos de matriz.